# Extract Substring in workflow

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow

I got words like "zzz_yyy_xxx" "zzzz_yyyy_xxxx"

I would like to extract the middle part (yyy) in the workflow but can't find the way out....

Since this is the description text in URL column, I am not able to use calculated column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to start extracting a character from the start (index 0) for one character until you find the first and last "-" characters. If you use a counter variable to keep track of the current loop instance, you should be able to get the start and end indices you need to use in order to get the text in the middle.

If that's not very helpful, I can work on adding an example.

Comment: I do not have much information about using loop in workflow. Example will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2013 or higher?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 Foundation

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't believe this can be done without a 2013 workflow.

Comment: Its okay, from your idea I solved the problem (though using many if-else branches) Thanks.